# Ionic Navigate from picture

Tags: html, css, json, typescript, ionic-framework

I have a section in my apps that loads data from a JSON file and displays pictures in a grid.

Example of JSON data:

```
"categories": [
    {
        "title": "Test",
        "image": "./assets/images/listing/200x200basquet.png",
        "page": "TestPage"
    },
```

Now I have a function when you click on one of the images it navigates you to 1 page, instead of different pages per image.

```
goToFeed(category: any) {
    console.log("Clicked goToFeed", category);
    this.nav.push(FeedPage, {
        category: category
    });
}
```

Does anybody have an idea on how can I re-write that function to specific navigate to the page that the image correlates?

Thanks

Comment: please share FeedPage code... If you want to show each of image indivudaly by clicking on image then you need to setup FeedPage

Comment: I want each image to navigate in a different Page ? For example the Title entry Test with 200x200basquet navigate to BasketPage

Comment: this.nav.push(FeedPage, { category: category }); you got trouble? Yea or not

Comment: Please check and give is it solve your problem or not...

Comment: console.log("Clicked goToFeed", category); please share it's output